# How to search content using SearchBox in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to search for some content within page using Search Box in Windows Store App. And when I write some text it should suggest data present on my page accordingly for example "Google.com" shows suggestion. Just Like That. Can anyone please suggest me coding for that ?

```
<SearchBox />
```

**Thanks & Regards,**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the AutoSuggestBox for searching with the help of TextChanged event of AutoSuggestBox. you can refer here for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx.

Please ignore if this AutoSuggestBox not suitable for your scenario.

Regards,

Elavarasan

Comment: Hi, you refer here to know how to use the AutoSuggestBox in your replication. Hope this will helps you. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/autosuggestbox-control-in-universal-apps/